# SQL Query - Get Most Recent Revision

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using T-Sql with SQL Server 2008.  Say I have parent table:

**Projects:**

```
ProjectID  ProjectNam
1          Test Project 1
2          Test Project 2
```

and child table **ProjectRevisions**:

```
ProjectRevID ProjectID DateCreated
11           1         10/15/2009
12           1         10/19/2009
13           1         10/25/2009
21           2         10/05/2009
```

**How do I end up with the most recent ProjectRevision for each Project?  Like this:**

```
ProjectRevID ProjectID DateCreated
13           1         10/25/2009
21           2         10/05/2009
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: Strictly speaking, to get the result shown doesn't require both tables.  It only requires ProjectRevisions.

Comment: He probably will want ProjectNam varchar in the final SELECT list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below will work regardless of any relationship between ProjectRevId and DateCreated.

```
SELECT *
FROM ProjectRevisions
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ProjectId
    , MAX(DateCreated) AS DateCreated
  FROM  ProjectRevisions
  GROUP BY ProjectId
  ) AS CurrentRevision
  ON CurrentRevision.ProjectId = ProjectRevisions.ProjectId
  AND CurrentRevision.DateCreated = ProjectRevisions.DateCreated
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select x.mProjectRevID, p.ProjectID, p.ProjectNam, x.mDateCreated
from Projects p
inner join
(
   select projectID
   , max(ProjectRevID) as mProjectRevID
   , max(DateCreated) as mDateCreated
   from ProjectRevisions
   group by ProjectID
) x
on x.projectID = p.ProjectID
```

assuming that ProjectRevID and DateCreated are both "going in the same direction" i.e. the next revision receives a higher ID than the previous one.

Joining from Projects allows you to access other columns from Projects, if need be.

Comment: ProjectRevID, in my actual database, is a GUID, so MAX(ProjectRevID) does not make sense.  Thanks for the help though,

Answer (score 1):

```
select ProjectRevID, ProjectID, DateCreated
from Projects p
  inner join ProjectRevisions
  on ProjectRevisions.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
where ProjectRevId = (
  select ProjecRevId
  from ProjectRevisions
  where ProjectId = p.ProjectId
  order by DateCreated desc
  limit 1
  )
```